# How to configure Nginx to only rate limit the API and not static files?

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting

Because `limit_req_zone` must be specified in HTTP context and cannot be in `server` or even in `location` context, it seems one can only set a rate limit for the entire server.

Nginx is used to serve static files and one may do this as often as they like. However, the `/api/...` path is proxied to the application server and should not be hit with a DoS attack. How can I configure Nginx to only rate limit the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to `limit_req_zone` is a key to keep a state for. The [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) tells us:

> Requests with an empty key value are not accounted.

To only rate limit certain parts of the site, we need to make those parts have a non-empty key. We can do this by mapping the `/api/...` URI space to the remote IP address and mapping everything else to an empty key:

```
http {
    [the rest of your configuration]

    map $uri $apicall {
        default "";
        ~api $binary_remote_addr;
    }
    limit_req_zone $apicall zone=mylimit:100m rate=10r/s;
}
```

Note that we use `$binary_remote_addr` as explained in [their rate limiting blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/).